# Inputting scoring (python 2.7.5)

Tags: python

I'm having trouble inputting scoring in my python quiz code. Here is the script:

```
 #This is the Test script for )TUKT(, Developed by BOT.
print ""
print "Welcome to the Ultimate Kirby Test."
print ""
begin = (raw_input("Would you like to begin?:"))
if begin == "yes":
    print ""
    print "Alright then! Let's start, shall we?"
    print "Q1. What color is Kirby?"
    print "1) Black."
    print "2) Blue."
    print "3) Pink."
    print "4) Technically, his color changes based on the opponent he swallows."
    choice = input("Answer=")
    if choice ==1:
        print "Incorrect."
        print ""
    elif choice ==2:
        print "Incorrect."
        print ""
    elif choice ==3:
        print "Tee hee.... I fooled you!"
        print ""
    elif choice ==4:
        score = score+1
        print "Well done! You saw through my trick!"
        print ""
    elif choice > 3 or choice < 1:
        print "That is not a valid answer."
        print ""
    print "Well done! You have finished my test quiz."
    print("Score:")
    print ""
#End of Script
```

The error always says
score = score+1 is not defined.
I did not get anywhere researching. 
Thanks! Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Set `score = 0` at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The varibale `score` has never been defined. Insert `score = 0` as first line of your scirpt.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to define a variable called `score`. You can't reference a value that doesn't exist!

Just declare it at the start:

```
score = 0
```

In the line `score = score + 1`, Python goes: *'so I need to create a variable called `score`. It contains the value of `score`, plus `1`.'* But `score` doesn't exist yet, so an error is thrown.